# Solr field alias for indexing and querying

Tags: solr

I have a set of documents in a Solr index that have the fields, exact_title and alternative_title. I want to be able to search them by using the field title.
So in other words the query `title:Hello World` should return documents that have an exact_title or an alternative_title "Hello World"

Is it possible to define as alias for a field during indexing time?

Comment: are these fields different or what? what's the idea behind them?

Comment: I have a set of books, some of them have two title, a main title and an alternative one. Strange, but not my dataset. I want it both titles to be searchable under the same field, with the minimum amount of data replication

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved defining copy fields in the schema.xml file.

Example:

```
<field name="title_txt" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="exact_title_txt" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="alternative_title_txt" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<copyField source="exact_title_txt" dest="title_txt"/>
<copyField source="alternative_title_txt" dest="title_txt"/>
```

Comment: Since both fields have the exact same type and the same content, I have to ask: What does this solve?

Comment: I want two or more fields to be searched using the same umbrella field

Comment: OK, when you added more fields and two copyField directives, it makes sense.